# Print minimize steps prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd, eclipse-clp

I'm working on a prolog program (CLPFD) with ECLiPSe 6.1. The program has a lot of variables and i want to minimize a certain value but (obviously) the minimization steps takes a lot of time. How can i print each solution found during the minimize phase? The output prints only (for instance) `Found a solution with cost 22003482` but not the solution itself. I would like to have:

```
Found a solution with cost 22003482
L = [[...],[...],...,[]] %L is the list of value to minimize
```

on each step of the minimization process.

I've tried this approach:

```
myLabeling([]).
myLabeling([H|T]):-
    labeling(H),
    myLabeling(T).

%code for the problem

%timeout(+Goal, ++TimeLimit, +TimeOutGoal)
timeout(minimize(myLabeling(AllNodesList),Result),TimeLimit,
    myLabeling(AllNodesList)).
```

where `AllNodesList` is a list of lists and `TimeOutGoal` is the goal to run when `TimeLimit` expires. This solution doesn't print the last solution found but the first non optimized solution found with labeling.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be asking two different questions: (1) how to print every intermediate solution found during minimization, and (2) how to get the best solution in case of a timeout.

**To print every solution found during minimization**, simply print the variables immediately after your labeling procedure succeeds:

```
minimize( (labeling(Variables),writeln(solution(Variables))), Cost)
```

**To use a timeout**, it is easiest is to use the [bb_min/3](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/branch_and_bound/bb_min-3.html) predicate from the [branch_and_bound](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/branch_and_bound/index.html) library. This is just like [minimize/2](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/branch_and_bound/minimize-2.html), but accepts various options, including timeout:

```
bb_min( labeling(Variables), Cost, bb_options{timeout:TimeLimit})
```

This will abort the search after the given time, and bind `Variables` to the best solution found within the time limit.